# Can I give the MVC Ajax callback a parameter?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, callback

```
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Pujar",
                    "BidOnSmallAuction", 
                    "Auctions",
                    new { id = @item.UniqueIdentifierID },
                    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divright" + item.UniqueIdentifierID, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "Update" },
                    new { @class = "btn primary" })
```

For example, when I click on this ActionLink, the javascript `"Update"` method will be called after the callback.

Since this ajax link is in many different auctions, each with it's own timer, I need to be able to tell the Update method which auction to run against.

So if you could tell me how to pass the Update method a parameter, I can figure out the rest.

Thanks for your time.

---

**Edit:**

Following the advice of both answers, I tried running the following:

```
//Just for testing purposes.
function Update(uniqueDivId) {
    alert(uniqueDivId);    
} 

//And in the view's code:

@Ajax.ActionLink("Pujar",
                 "BidOnSmallAuction",
                 "Auctions",
                 new { id = @item.UniqueIdentifierID },
                 new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divright" + item.UniqueIdentifierID,               
                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                                   OnSuccess = "function() { Update(3); }" },
                 new { @class = "btn primary" })
```

The alert message isn't being called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
   "Pujar",
   "BidOnSmallAuction",
   "Auctions",
   new { id = @item.UniqueIdentifierID },
   new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divright" + item.UniqueIdentifierID,
                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                     OnSuccess = "function() { Update(someParam); }" },
   new { @class = "btn primary" })
```

Such that OnSuccess itself calls a function that has no parameters, but that function in turn knows how to call Update() with parameters. You should be able to use string concatenation to setup the parameters as you need them (similar to how you did for `UpdateTargetId`), for example:

```
...
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divright" + item.UniqueIdentifierID,
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "function() { Update(" + item.UniqueIdentifierID + "); }" },
...
```

UPDATE:

Oh, sorry, looks like per-maybe-haps it is expecting just the name of a function as a string where I thought it was expecting a reference to the function.

Can you dynamically include other scripts on the page at the same time as your existing code? If so, change the above to say `OnSuccess="UpdateProxy"` and then dynamically output the following:

```
<script>
function UpdateProxy() {
   Update(/* insert your item.UniqueIdentifierID or other params here */);
}
</script>
```

If you have multiple ajax links on the page at the same time you'd need to have `UpdateProxy1(), UpdateProxy2()` and so forth.

Comment: This is good advice, and on first glance it would seem this would work, but unfortunately the Update method isn't invoked on the callback. This is the exact HTML that's rendered on my page: `data-ajax-success="function() { Update(3); }"` - Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the only other suggestion I can think of. I haven't run into this problem before because I haven't used the @Ajax.ActionLink method you're using: I tend to do my ajax stuff by including some jQuery so I have complete control rather than worrying about what does or doesn't get generated for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
OnSuccess = "function() { Update(\"some param\"); }"
```

Comment: Yes, this seemed like it would work, but the Update method isn't being invoked during the callback. Even when calling `Update(3)` without concatenation of parameters, the method isn't invoked. Any ideas?